# Restricting admin urls to already authenticated superusers in Django

Tags: django, django-urls, superuser

I've searched around for some solutions to this, but they all focus on a single admin url. However I was wondering if there is a way to restrict ALL the admin views, not the accounts to already authenticated superusers.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

What I want is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', is_superuser(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

Or something like this that I can do in the view

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser, login_url='allauth.account.views.LoginView')
def superuser_only(request, template):
    return render(request, template)
```

but still allows me to use `admin.site.urls`.

Is there a quick and elegant way to solve this? I want all users including the superuser to authenticate through `accounts` app.

Comment: You could create a middleware to verify the user and the request path and redirect to the `accounts` app when necessary.

Comment: But how do I "initiate" the admin.site.urls from within a view?

Comment: @arcegk My primary goal is to return a 404 if the user is not a superuser. To "trick" people into thinking the admin urls has been removed.

Comment: Middlewares are checked before views take a look to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/)

Comment: Ahhh, I'll take a look there :) However, is it possible to check if a url belongs to admin? Like reverse the whole app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a middleware class that checks the `request.path` and the `user` and add it to the `MIDDLEWARE` var in your settings.

```
from django.http import Http404

class SuperUserMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        user = request.user
        is_anonymous = user.is_anonymous()
        if 'admin' in request.path
            if not is_anonymous:
                if not user.is_superuser:
                    raise Http404
            else:
                raise Http404
```